# Почему не работает https сертификат?

Tags: https, certbot

Настраивал Lets Encrypt сертификаты при помощи certbot.

Когда я первый раз настраивал сертификаты https я сначала это сделал для site1.com потом для остальных site2.com , site3.com и site4.com . Все на одном сервере. Таким образом для каждого сайта свой сертификат и все работало.

Но, спустя какое то время я заметил что сайты которые настраивались после site1.com не работают и браузер говорит что типа проблемы с сертификатом. Я пробил сертификаты этих сайтов и выяснилось что они принадлежат почему то site1.com. Долго не мог понять что произошло. Что за баг, начал гуглить ничего не нагуглил но нашел способ как все сайты на одном сервере обьеденить в один сертификат, сделал, все супер, но это не очень круто. Сегодня я решил еще раз более внимательно настроить для каждого сайта СВОЙ сертификат https. Сделал. Все работало какое то время и опять!!! Опять через несколько минут все слетело. Короче вот что я думаю: этот certbot сволочь такая, как то проверяет сервер и если находит там несколько сертификатов для разных сайтов, то их удаляет или портит, я незнаю что он делает, но в итоге остается работоспособным только самый первый сайт site1.com . Ну никак не получается сделать для каждого свой, хоть ты застрелись.

Получал сертификаты этой командой:

```
certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/letsencrypt -d site.com -d www.site.com
```

Может кто то сталкивался с этой проблемой, подскажите что происходит?

Comment: Есть вот какое подозрение. Если у Вас на сервере несколько сайтов, то не стоит ли перед ними nginx, который разруливает по доменному имени, куда кидать пользователя? Если это так - КАЖЕТСЯ, nginx'у требуются отдельные настройки на сертификаты LetsEncrypt. Если nginx'а нет - отпишитесь, еще подумаем...

Comment: Да. Стоит nginx. Но ведь для каждого домена в секции server указан путь к своему конфигу для сертификата  include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-site.com.conf; Внутри которого прописано ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.com/privkey.pem;  Так что .... хм..

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, вот этот ответ на вопрос: здесь именно Ваш случай, nginx - letsencrypt - multiple sites. Если что то будет непонятно - напишите в комментариях? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/letsencrypt-for-multiple-domains-on-nginx

Comment: Спасибо, я уже разобрался и написал ответ. Вы меня подтолкнули к этому =)

Answer (score 2):

Нашол решение вопроса: оказывается я забыл о директиве server_name
Вместо этого:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-site.com.conf;
include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;
limit_conn connection_ip 100;
}
```

Нужно сделать это:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl;
index index.php;
server_name site.com www.site.com;
include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-site.com.conf;
include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;
root /var/www/site.com/public;
. . . 
. . .
}
```

B так, для каждого домена (поддомена).
А так, получается что для всех доменов был прописан одинаковый код и nginx путался.